# Error *** stack smashing detected ***: terminated C++

Tags: c++

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]El ejercicio es fácil, generar una matriz 4x20 (simulando una planilla de 20 alumnos y 4 materias) que se carguen con números aleatorios. El problema es que al finalizar el código me sale el error *** stack smashing detected ***

Fragmento del código que creo que contiene el error abajo.

```
for (j = 0 ; j < 20; j++){
    sumpers=0;
  for (k = 0 ; k < 4; k++){
  sumpers = sumpers + mat[j][k];
}
float prompers = float (sumpers) / 4;
  cout << "el promedio personal del alumno " << j << " es " <<prompers<<" \n";
  if (prompers>may){
      may=prompers;
  }
}
cout<<"El mejor alumno tiene promedio "<<may<<"\n";
```

Por otro lado, que no estoy encontrando manera de plantear, es que el código debe encontrar la ubicación y mostrar solo su posición de columna del alumno con mejor promedio.
Este es la primera parte del código.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int j, k, mat[4][20], sumpers=0, may=0;
float prompers=0;
srand(time(NULL));
for (j=0 ; j<20 ; j++){
    for (k=0 ; k<4 ; k++){
        mat[j][k]=0 + rand() % (6-0);
        cout<<mat[j][k]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"<--alumno "<<j;
    cout<<endl;
}
cout<<endl;
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: que tiene que ver c# con esta pregunta????

Answer (score 2):

`mat` fue declarada como `int mat[4][20]`, sin embargo, en el ciclo `for` estás escribiendo en índices fuera de estos límites, por ejemplo, cuando `j = 19` se escriben los valores `mat[19][0]` hasta `mat[19][3]`. Supongo que querrás invertir los índices en la expresión `mat[j][k]=0 + rand() % (6-0);` por `mat[k][j]=0 + rand() % (6-0);`. El mensaje *stack smashing detected* justamente indica que estás escribiendo valores en áreas de memoria que no deberías.